# Configuring connection support for spring social in XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am working spring mvc that integrated spring social. I cannot understand the following configuration that is provided by user guide at

http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html (4.2.1 Configuring connection support in XML)

```
<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository" factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
<constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
```

What does it means by "#{request.userPrincipal.name}" or what is the value of it. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [Spring EL - Expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

Nerveless the reference documentation does not mention `request` as a special variable in spring el. But this must not mean anything: may I did not have a look at the right places or it is just one more poorly documented feature.

---

See this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/eadno1/spring-has-got-me-under-its-spel): so it is really a spring EL Expression.

Comment: I have asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885847/list-of-spring-el-variables - to get get a list of the predefined Spring EL variables.