# List of Spring EL Variables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

Spring EL supports a some predefined variables

- `{#systemProperties. ... }`
- `{#systemEnvironment. ... }`
- `{#request. ...}`
- `{#session. ...}`

The first two once are documented in the [Spring Reference: chapter 6. Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef).
The two others are not mentioned in the Spring Reference (or I did not found them.) (I found them in this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/eadno1/spring-has-got-me-under-its-spel), as well as its usage in [spring social](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7885055/280244)).

**So my question is: is there a more or less complete list of predefined spring-el variables?**

I guess that some of this predefined variables are not defined by spring core itself, but by "activating" of some modules like spring-mvc. So I am interested in the the variables **that are available in a more or less common spring + jpa + mvc + security application**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not answer your root question but I may give you a hint.

There are some predefined beans registered at start up of your application context but which  depends on the context type you are using.

Commonly, `systemProperties` and `systemEnvironment` are present. Loading Spring within a web application, you will also get `servletContext`, `contextParameters` and `contextAttributes`. I assume, `request` and `session` are related to a web application context as well.

I discovered this during debugging of my application which uses Spring 3.0.6RELEASE. A good starting point is SpringBeanELResolver.getValue() method.

Answer (score 8):

I also notice that `environment` resolves to the current `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` instance. I am not sure this is a documented feature, but I was looking for a concise way to do the following in my `@Configuration` class:

```
@Value("#{environment.acceptsProfiles('test')}")
private boolean test;
```

Which then allows me to switch off this value in further bean defintions.

I have submitted the following JIRA to address this issue:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9037