# SpEL - access session object in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

Is there a way to access session object within SpEL expression? Specifically I need it in spring security, something like

```
<intercept-url pattern="/somePage.html" access="session.getAttribute('someTemporaryFlag') != null" />
```

This code returns: `EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'session' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'`. There's a related question to this one: [List of Spring EL Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885847/list-of-spring-el-variables) but it doesn't answer my question.

Solution with security roles is not acceptable.

Comment: Provided code is not working for you?

Comment: No it returns SpelEvaluationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have access to the session object directly but you can access request object and get session from it.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/somePage.html" 
       access="request.session.getAttribute('someTemporaryFlag') != null" />
```