# Is it possible to get request param in SPEL in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have simple rest repository:

```
TestRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, String> {
    @PreAuthorize("@helper.hasPermissionToProjection(#projection)")
    @Override
    Page<Test> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

What I need is to pass `projection` param from the link `api/tests?projection=full` to my bean's `hasPermissionToProjection` method.

Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Interesting question. This post refers to a predefined SPEL variable `request`. i.e. `#request.projection`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885847/list-of-spring-el-variables